# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/DocumentException : Dom4j-1.6.1.jar is already added in BuildPath

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

I am trying to run below program (using hibernate 3, IDE = Eclipse, I am not using Maven as I am developing it on a development server , where we don't use Maven) :

```
package test;

import org.hibernate.Hibernate;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.Session;

public class TestDAO {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.configure();
        SessionFactory sf = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
        Session ses = sf.openSession();
        Query query  = ses.createSQLQuery("select my_seq.nextval as num from dual").addScalar("num", Hibernate.LONG);
        Long key=(Long)query.uniqueResult();
        System.out.println("here is the next valfrom sequcne : "+key);
        ses.close();
        sf.close();

    }

}
```

I am using oracle sequence (my_seq) to get next value in hibernate:

```
select my_seq.nextval as num from dual
```

I am getting below error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/DocumentException
    at test.TestDAO.main(TestDAO.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dom4j.DocumentException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Launcher.java:229)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 1 more
```

I have already added the Dom4j-1.6.1.jar file in my java build path.
But still I am getting the error :java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dom4j.DocumentException

Most of the google solutions are to add Dom4j-1.6.1.jar to java build path , which i already have done.

Please suggest some solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should check that the Dom4j JAR file actually includes the class.  I suspect it does, but it only takes a few seconds to "grep" the output of `jar -tf Dom4j-1.6.1.jar` ...

Assuming that the class is in the JAR, then the problem is that the JAR file needs to be on the (run-time) classpath *as well as* on the (compile-time) build path.  This exception is happening when you run your unit test.  So check the classpath that is in effect for your unit tests.

---

> I am not using Maven as I am developing it on a development server , where we don't use Maven ...

I'm not convinced that is a good idea.  It is unlikely that you would have this problem with Maven, either in Eclipse or not.  And the logic strikes me as somewhat circular.  Why would you not want to use Maven on a development server?

**UPDATE** - Apparently the reason your development server is not using Maven is that someone else controls it.  But even that strikes me as odd.  Why would your client (?) or hosting company (?) want to prevent that?

Comment: Hi Stephen C,

1. I checked the Dom4j-1.6.1jar file , it do contain the class : DocumentException.class file.

2. I am not sure how to make my Jar available on run-time as well as compile-time classpath. Can you describe how can I do that.


3. Yes the dev environment we are given don't use Maven and it managed by third party.

Comment: I am directly running my main class as a Java application.
The program I wrote (see code attached with the first question) has a main class and I was running it as a java application.

Additionally , I also checked that dom4j-1.6.1.jar is in both Java Buildpath and the WEB-INF/lib folder.

Comment: Please assist.
This issue is really eating my whole day, without having a solution.

Comment: Please read this page of the Oracle doc which explains all about the Java classpath: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html.  Note that when you run Java code (e.g. your test class) from the command line ... the classpath has to be set explicitly.  (By contrast, the classpath is set automatically to include WEB-INF/lib ... when your code is run as a webapp.)